# How to change hibernate mapping properties at runtime

Tags: hibernate

I have an entity in which i have specified lazy="false" and batch-size="100". It is working fine but in some other scenario i want to remove batch -size and set lazy="true". If i change hbm files then it affect other applications. Is there any way i can change properties of entity for current session only before executing hql.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the fetching strategy (lazy or not) at runtime by HQL or criteria query.
In HQL your can use *fetch join* to initialize values of a joined collection, example:

```
from Cat as cat
inner join fetch cat.mate
left join fetch cat.kittens
```

See [Hibernate Doku - 15.3. Associations and joins](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Use [Criteria.setFetchMode(..)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Criteria.html) of criteria api instead for criteria queries, example:

```
List cats = sess.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.add( Restrictions.like("name", "Fritz%") )
.setFetchMode("mate", FetchMode.EAGER)
.setFetchMode("kittens", FetchMode.EAGER)
.list();
```

Hibernate Doku for this: [16.5. Dynamic association fetching](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching)

Answer (score 2):

You can change the fetching strategy using [Fetching Profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-profiles).

Comment: As I know there is no way to change a batch size dynamically. You can probably change it at configuration time by modifying the Configuration object used to create the SessionFactory. See org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getClasses() and org.hibernate.mapping.Collection.setBatchSize().

Comment: You can find additional information related to fetching at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.
The full details are [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).